# Getting this error in Heroku logs: Don't know how to build task 'jobs:work'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I've been troubleshooting a rails app I pushed to an existing Heroku app. Whenever I submit user input from the home page, I receive a 500 error: `We're sorry, but something went wrong.`

This is what I get back when I run `heroku logs`:

```
2014-12-15T22:59:50.824951+00:00 app[worker.1]: rake aborted!
2014-12-15T22:59:50.824977+00:00 app[worker.1]: Don't know how to build task 'jobs:work'
```

I'm not sure what steps I should take fix this, so any insights would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: try `heroku run rake -T|grep jobs` on heroku console, and provide output

Comment: do you have a worker in your Procfile that is calling that rake task?

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a work-around than a solution:

Add a (blank) rake task called `jobs:work`.

```
# lib/tasks/jobs.rake
namespace :jobs do
  task work: :environment do |t|
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I started getting this error when my Hobby dyno went over the hours allowed per month

Run `heroku run rake -T|grep jobs` and if you get `Free app running time quota exhausted` then there you have it...